# Spring Cloud Gateway filter read and modify response body

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to read and modify the response body in the filter. I have added a custom filter to read and modify the changes but didn't found any option to read the body part. I can change the headers and cookie but not the body of the response

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, CustomGatewayFilterFactory extractFilter) {
     
        return builder.routes()
           
                .route("ccprest",r -> r.path("/api/details/**").
                        filters( f -> f.filter(extractFilter.apply(new ExtractCCPUrlGatewayFilterFactory.Config()))).uri(http://localhost:8090/test))

                                
                .build();
    }
```

Custom filter

```
@CommonsLog
public class  CustomGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory< CustomGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

    protected static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();


    public CustomGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
       return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build()).s
      then(
                    Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();

               //response.getBody() //Dont know how to read and modify the body 

                        Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest()
                                .getQueryParams()
                                .getFirst("include-total"))
                                .ifPresent(qp -> {
                                    String responseContentLanguage = "hai";

                                    response.getHeaders()
                                            .add("Bael-Custom-Language-Header", responseContentLanguage);
                                });
                    }));



        }, 10);
    }

    public static class Config {

    }

}
```